Empirical estimation of distribution function $F(x,y)$
For the random variables $X$ and $Y$ consider the distribution function $F(x,y)$. Empirical estimation of  $F(x,y)$ is given by $$\widehat{F}(x,y)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n I(X<x,Y<y)=\begin{cases}1&(X<x,Y<y),\\
0&\textrm{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$
I want to write the R code for $$H(t)=\int_0^t \widehat{F}^2(x,t)dx.$$
Edit:$$H(t)=\int_0^s \widehat{F}^2(x,t)dx$$

The definition at How to Compute Bivariate Empirical Distribution?  with $\le $, where you have $<$ is more usual, but I have seen your definition in some French books ... I will use the more usual
$$ \begin{align}\widehat{F}(x, y)&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n I(X\le x,Y\le y)\\&=\begin{cases}1&(X\le x,Y\le y),\\
0&\textrm{otherwise}.\end{cases}\end{align}
$$
The integral becomes
\begin{align}
H(t)&=\int_0^t \widehat{F}^2(x,t)~dx \\
&=\int_0^t \frac1n \sum_1^n \mathbb{1}(x_i\le t) \mathbb{1}(y_i\le t) \frac1n \sum_1^n \mathbb{1}(x_j \le t)\mathbb{1}(y_j\le t) \; dx \\ 
&=\frac1{n^2}\sum_i \sum_j \mathbb{1}(y_i\le t) \mathbb{1}(y_j\le t) \cdot \int_0^t \mathbb{1}(x_i \le x)\mathbb{1}(x_j\le x) \; dx .\\
\end{align}
First concentrating on the last integral:
$$ \int_0^t \mathbb{1}(x_i \le x)\mathbb{1}(x_j\le x) \; dx = \\
\int_0^t \mathbb{1}(\max(x_i, x_j)\le t)\; dx = \max(0, t-\max(x_i, x_j)), 
$$ and using that
\begin{align}
H(t)&= \frac1{n^2}\sum_i \sum_j \mathbb{1}(\max(y_i, y_j)\le t)\cdot \max(0, t-\max(x_i, x_j)), 
\end{align}
and then converting that to R code should be trivial.

Nicely put (+1). I thought there was a missing indicator symbol in the penultimate computation, which I have included but if it is not, you may revert it back.

@kjetil Actually I wanted to find for $H(t)=\int_0^s \widehat{F}^2(x,t)~dx$, by mistake I took limit from 0 to t. Can you reviews please if possible?

Out of time now, but will try
